# How to create a very large BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to add two very big integers

```
  46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
+ 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250;
```

What's wrong with this?

```
BigInteger f = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250;
```

How I can solve this problem in Java using `BigInteger`?

Comment: Why do you assume that should work? What error message does it show?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is that `3710...` will be interpreted as an `int`, and so it will be out of range. Essentially what you're trying to do is to create an `int`, and then convert it to a `BigInteger`, and the first step of this will fail because an `int` can't store a number that large.

You need to use the constructor that takes a `String`:

```
BigInteger f = new BigInteger("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250");
```

and similarly for your other `BigInteger`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Java does not have built-in support for `BigInteger` literals - you cannot write this:

```
BigInteger f = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250;
```

Use the constructor of `BigInteger` that takes a `String` instead:

```
BigInteger f = new BigInteger("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250");
```

To add two `BigInteger` objects:

```
BigInteger f = new BigInteger("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250");
BigInteger g = new BigInteger("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");

BigInteger sum = f.add(g);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to construct your BigInteger from a String, not a numerical literal, as this cannot work as it is converted to an int first.

Answer (score 1):

Try [add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)) like:

```
BigInteger number1 = new BigInteger("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");
BigInteger number2 = new BigInteger("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250");
BigInteger sum = number1.add(number2);
```

BigInteger's object needs to be created using new operator and you are trying to assign number directly as bigInteger which is no a valid statement. You could pass that number as a string to BigInteger's constructor as above.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the statement as

```
BigInteger f = new BigInteger("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250");

BigInteger g = new BigInteger("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");
```

Now, for addition

```
BigInteger sum = f.add(g);
```

For multiplication

```
BigInteger product = f.multiply(g);
```

And so on.

You can't use `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` operators in case of BigIntegers unlike other variable types. You need to use methods for each of the operations.