# Pig latin biginteger literal

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to embed a biginteger literal in a pig latin script?

e.g

```
x < 12345678901234567890
```

where x is a biginteger. The above gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried appending an `L`? Like `12345678901234567890L`

Comment: I have and it seems to work. I haven't exhaustively tested yet, but isn't `L` supposed to be used for long numbers?

Comment: You're right, `L` will only give you a long. Since Pig BigIntegers should be Java BigIntegers, it seems there's no way to create a literal. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606306/how-to-create-a-very-large-biginteger